# Heroku persistent $PATH with muliple buildpacks

Tags: node.js, heroku, less

I'm trying to run a `compress` ([django compressor](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to minimize `CSS` and `js` files on my `Heroku`instance, but I can't install `less`.

> build progress log

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  4.1.1
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Downloading and installing node 4.1.1...
       Using default npm version: 2.14.4
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules (not cached - skipping)
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules (nothing to cache)
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
       └── (empty)

-----> Python app detected
     $ pip install -r requirements.txt
-----> Running post-compile hook
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less/-/less-2.7.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/less/-/less-2.7.1.tgz
npm WARN engine less@2.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.12"} (current: {"node":"v0.8.12","npm":"1.1.63"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/errno
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/image-size
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/promise
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/image-size
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing mkdirp@^0.5.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing mime@^1.2.11
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing graceful-fs@^4.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/image-size/-/image-size-0.5.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing source-map@^0.5.3
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/image-size/-/image-size-0.5.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/errno
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing errno@^0.1.1
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/promise
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing promise@^7.1.1
npm WARN engine image-size@0.5.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.8.12","npm":"1.1.63"})
less@2.7.1 node_modules/less
└── image-size@0.5.1
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 72.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v159
       https://<my-app>.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "a really cool test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.1.1"
  }
}
```

> post_compile hook

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH=/app/.heroku/node/bin:$PATH
npm install less
```

Why isn't this working? It looks like the correct version of `Node.js` get's installed but then somehow get removed from the `$PATH`. I'm guessing that `$PATH` is not persistent between multiple build packs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying to install less in a post_compile hook.
Why not just add it directly to your package.json, by running the following (in your development environment), and then adding the modified package.json to your git repo pushed to Heroku:

```
npm install less --save
```

Comment: yes, that would be my next step but I can't even get the correct node version into my $PATH because it looks like $PATH get's reset between build packs so I'm not too optimistic about this. Will try though thanks

Comment: If you are concerned that the python buildpack is messing up your node environment, you could consider reversing the order of the buildpacks (i.e.  loading the python buildpack first, and then the node buidpack). See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app#setting-a-buildpack.